# Symfony Class Not Found

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-process

I am getting the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\\Component\\Process\\PhpProcess' not found in ...
```

It's my first time using Symfony. I download the files from the [GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/Process) site. Since the downloaded files are of the Process directory, I created folders in order to have the correct path. (Symfony/Component/Process/*DOWNLOADED FILES*).

I placed the Symfony directory in the main directory (where my index file is).

Is this how you install Symfony? (Note I only need the Process sub-directory and not the whole framework)

For now I am using this ready-made code, just to see if I can get it running:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\PhpProcess;

    $command = file_get_contents('/hello_world.php');

    if ( $command ) {
        $process = new PhpProcess($command); //<----- GETTING ERROR HERE 
        $process->run();

        if ($process->isSuccessful()) {

            $output = $process->getOutput();
            // ... 
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception($process->getErrorOutput());
        }
    }
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it please? Is it due to a bad path?

Comment: I am using Heroku, if that is of any help

Answer (score 2):

I think it has to do with namespace registration, have you checked that the namespace that defines the class is loaded?, check the [ClassLoader reference](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/class_loader.html)

Check the autoload.php file inside your `app` directory

Comment: Hi I copied the namespace from ready-made code. I assume its correct. I think my problem is the location where I placed the files.

Comment: Did you include the required files?

Comment: Check the autoload.php file